# mvc scaffolding viewmodel not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffolding

My project was working fine, but now I try to add a new View and I get the error: "there was an error running the selected code generator unable to retrieve metadata for TravelAgencyMVC.Models.ViewModel.ToursPackageView'

My model:

```
    namespace TravelAgencyMVC.Models.ViewModel
{
    public class ToursPackageView
    {
        [Key]
        public int ToursPackageID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Image")]
        public string Image { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Welcome">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TravelAgencyDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.TravelAgencyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.TravelAgencyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.TravelAgencyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TravelAgencyDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

My DbContext:

```
public partial class TravelAgencyDBEntities : DbContext
{

    public TravelAgencyDBEntities()
        : base("name=TravelAgencyDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ToursPackage> ToursPackages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TravelAgencyMVC.Models.ViewModel.UserSignUpView> UserSignUpViews { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TravelAgencyMVC.Models.ViewModel.UserLoginView> UserLoginViews { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TravelAgencyMVC.Models.ViewModel.ToursPackageView> ToursPackageViews { get; set; }
}
```

}

I already check the connectionStrings and the provider. They look fine. Does anyone know what is causing that error?

Thanks

Comment: Its a view model. It should not have a `[Key]` attribute or any relationship with EF.

Comment: Nope. I removed that and still the same problem

Comment: And the last 3 lines of your code where you associated it with your context?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean about these lines? It is in the TravelAgencyDBEntities, isn't it?

Comment: You need to delete `public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TravelAgencyMVC.Models.ViewModel.ToursPackageView> ToursPackageViews { get; set; }` - its a view model! - it should have no relationship at all with your database context